# Can I type 1/2 in sympy python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, sympy

I have the hamiltonian for harmonic oscillator where I would like to see (n+1/2) but sympy see 1/2 is zero or if I type 1/2.0 =0.5 . Is it possible to keep as 1/2 and at the same time it maintains as an fraction not a symbol? Thanks,

Comment: Python has the `fractions` module that could represent 1/2 as an object, but I don't know if sympy is compatible with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to type `Rational(1, 2)`, or, more concisely, `S(1)/2`.

See http://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/gotchas.html#two-final-notes-and. `1/2` is entirely Python:  no SymPy types are involved. The only way to get Python from doing what it does with int/int (integer division in Python 2 and float division in Python 3 or Python 2 with `from __future__ import division`) is to use a SymPy type somewhere, which is what both of the above do.